# Bathroom Vent Question

Tags: plumbing

I'm putting in a bathroom sink drain in Canada, Ontario.

We had a plumber come in who told us there was no vent for this drain and it would cost a lot to install. We contacted another plumber, who said all we needed to do was install an AAV.

I'm a little confused because it looks like there is a vent connected.

[image]

The washing machine also connects to this vent and then travels to the kitchen (about a 10ft run)

[image]

I have two questions. Is an AAV required if there's already a connection to the vent and would a ptrap be required in the sink cabinet if there's already one below it in the basement?

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: The p-trap is required.  Would need to know the plumbing code for the distance allowed between a sink and vent to know if another vent is required or need an AAV

Comment: Thanks for your response. This is what I found from searching https://www.buildingcode.online/1090.html. It states there can be a 1000mm vertical plane and a 3m horizontal plane.